# Is there a way in which Pinterest can be integrated with an android Application

Tags: android, integration, pinterest

I wish to drop pins or view the photo's which are of my interest in my Android Application, do we have any SDK by pinterest , as I would want to integrate the same inside my Android Application.

Any suggestions would be like a boon

Comment: Do you mean you want to write an application like this? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinterest

Comment: I want to integrate its SDK so that i can drop a photo I take from My Camera , to the Pinterest Account using My own Application. (btw nice one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.pinterest.com/android/

This is for others who might want to get started with pinterest and land in this page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the answer is "not yet"... But go and sign up with them, I'm sure it's on their radar and will come soon enough if it's in their basic FAQ.

https://support.pinterest.com/entries/21151603-i-m-a-developer-does-pinterest-have-a-public-api

Another option (or just for the meantime before they release an official API) may be if the official pinterest app offers an intent for sharing? Plenty of other social web entities like twitter, facebook, etc give intent based access in their official apps, that let you dump media, links, etc into them from other apps in the system, and have the information posted to your accounts.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the info, I would sign up with them for now, I guess this would be the answer for now, actually i really wanted to get the "dump" via my own app rather than forcing there intent to open their activity, that helped anyways